# I am not able to log on to the Windows Recovery Tool

Tags: windows-xp, password-recovery, system-repair-disc, bootrepair

Computer is running Windows XP, User was possibly scammed, has been locked out of his computer.

I tried using the NT Password Recovery tool from here:
http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/main.html

That claims that i have reset the password to blank and unlocked it, but it never seems to actually go through.

I have then attempted to run the Windows repair text based tool from a bootable USB, which simply asks me for the Administrator Password, which i cant reset.

Not able to get into Safe Mode either as i can reset the password.

Please Help Guys!

Comment: Also guys forgot to mention, for some reason the account is no longer mentioned in the chntpw edit user info & menu

Comment: XP Home or Pro version??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SO guys,

ended up just biting the bullet using ophcrack to crack the NTLM Hashes, managed to get it eventually and get into the admin account and get back into the original user i was trying to get back to

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

If the Windows XP is using encryption and you force it to delete the password and allow you access to the operating system, then XP will allow access to the operating system but it will deny access to all of the users individual files which will stay encrypted and will probably not be easily recovered. However if you use a different type of program which cracks the password rather than break or delete the password then all encrypted data can be recovered. The main drawback to cracking the password via a program is that it can sometimes take hours before a match is found.

This is perhaps the best free password cracker software for windows XP and Vista, but as I said it can take time. Sometimes hours.

http://ophcrack.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I have all the files backed up before i bothered trying everything (Force of habit) i did think about cracking the password with Ophcrack, but was hoping of a quicker solution!

Will definitely look into using a cracker now. Thanks for your comment!